# jpa many to many getting back data

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many, hibernate-mapping

I have two entity
employee:

```
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int emp_id;

    private String name;

    private String email;

    private String phone;

    @ManyToMany(
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL

    )
    @JoinTable(name = "EMP_PRO_DB", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "empId", referencedColumnName = "emp_id")
    },
    inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "proId", referencedColumnName = "pro_id")
    })
    private Set<Project> projects = new HashSet<>();

}
```

Project:

```
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int pro_id;

    private String projectName;

    private String projectType;
    @JsonIdentityInfo(
            generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
            property = "emp_id"
    )
    @ManyToMany(
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL

    )
    @JoinTable(name = "EMP_PRO_DB", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "proId", referencedColumnName = "pro_id")
    },
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "empId", referencedColumnName = "emp_id")
            })
    private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>();
}
```

When i fetch all data from employee, the json returns me :
[image]

which is correct, it can show me  the projects that the employee has.

BUT when i fetch all data from project, the json returns me:
[image]

Employee 1 has two project, it shows one, employee 2 has one project but its only showing the ID, I will need the details of that employee (at leas the name)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you tried to create a bidirectional relationship between `Employee` and `Project`.

But instead you created two conceptually independent relationships, one from `Employee` to `Project` and one in the reverse direction, that just happen to write into the same tables.
This of course is bound to cause troubles.

The fix is to convert this into a proper bidirectional relationship.

Change the `Project` side of the relationship to

```java
    @ManyToMany(
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedby="projects"
    )
    private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>();
```

Note that with this mapping only the `Employee` side of the relationship will be used while persisting. You'll have to keep the two sides in sync on the Java side yourself.

Comment: I have dropped all the three tables, and updated PROJECT.java
But after adding in data. 
The returned data still looks the same